# Error searching first occurence

Tags: python-2.7, list

I have a list in python and I'm searching the first occurrence of a value (>=5000000), but it returns the first of >=500000.
Here the command:

```
First_Range_Init_Freq = next(x for x in Freq_Cust if x > '5000000.000')
```

The strange is, it works fine if I search an exact value in the list with "==", but returns wrong value if I search something bigger or equal ">=".

Any ideas?

Comment: You compare it with a *string*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if  I understand problem correctly (insufficient data).
Are you trying to,

- 1) Get first occurrence of value >=5000000 in a list?
- 2) Or its position?
- 3) You are comparing a `int`   (>=5000000) with a `string`x >
  '5000000.000'

Anyway, If its first occurrence you are trying to find you can use  array index  method  as below. (problem using a sample list)

```
Freq_Cust = ['4800000.000', '5000000.000' , '5000001.000',   '50000010.000', '4900000.000', '500000.000' ]

First_Range_Init_Freq = [Freq_Cust.index(x) for x in Freq_Cust if x >= '5000000.000'][0]
print Freq_Cust[First_Range_Init_Freq]
```

Result:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
5000000.000
>>>
```

For its position you can get using,

```
>>> print First_Range_Init_Freq
1
```

I am assuming you are comparing string with string or int with int. Else you will need to balance the comparision with correct type.

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for. And update question with more details.

**EDIT1**
Based on your comments. I believe the problem is that you are comparing a number as text and hence its giving incorrect result.

For e.g. see below,

```
>>> '5000000' == '5000000.000'
False
>>> '5000000.000' > '5000000'
True
>>> 5000000 == 5000000.000
True
>>>
```

A textual '5000000' is not = '5000000.000' , while a `int` 5000000 number is = float 5000000.000.

So, if you map your list values to float and also the comparision is done with a float , it will yield correct result.

Freq_Cust = ['4800000', '5000000' , '5000001',   '50000010', '49000000', '500000' ]

```
Freq_Cust = map(float,Freq_Cust)

First_Range_Init_Freq = [Freq_Cust.index(x) for x in Freq_Cust if x >= float('5000000.000')][0]
print Freq_Cust[First_Range_Init_Freq]

>>> 
5000000.0
>>>
```

Ofcourse you can just compare using x >= 5000000.000 or x >= 5000000.

If your list values are part `int` and part `float`, you may want to `map` to `float` as a catch-all solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! :)
It's the first time I'm programming with Python, that's why I'm facing these problems...

I'm trying to get the first occurrence of value >=5000000.000 in a list, AND also its position in the list.
I'm reading these values out of a file, and thought in the list these values were all floats, but apparently not.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! :)
It's the first time I'm programming with Python, that's why I'm facing these problems...

I'm trying to get the first occurrence of value >=5000000.000 in a list, AND also its position in the list.
I tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

I'm reading these values out of a file, and thought in the list these values were all floats, but apparently not. I tried to convert it to float ([float(Freq_Cust) for i in Freq_Cust]), it executes the command, but returns "False" when I type command "type(Freq_Cust) is float".
Do I have to convert list to float?

Comment: Great, now it's working!  :)   I'm new with Python and it was really a problem when comparing string with int, so I had to convert all strings to int to compare.
Thank you very much for helping, I really appreciate it.   :)

Comment: @CassianoSilva , Glad to help. Do accept the answer so that question is marked as answered and does not hang in the pool of unanswered questions. Any up-vote will be appreciated as well.